# How to update data in mongowith spring boot and mongo and react

Tags: java, mongodb, reactjs

I am writing a spring boot application with MongoDB integration. i have several files which I am writing here.

```
ProductController.java
package com.spring.restapi.controllers;

import com.spring.restapi.models.product;
import com.spring.restapi.repositories.ProductRepository;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.http.MediaType;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.CrossOrigin;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PathVariable;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestBody;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

@RestController
public class ProductController {

    @Autowired
    ProductRepository productRepository;


    @CrossOrigin(origins = "http://localhost:8080")
    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET, value ="/products")
    public Iterable<product> product(){
            return productRepository.findAll();
    }

    @CrossOrigin(origins = "http://localhost:8080")
    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST, value= "/products", consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    public String save(@RequestBody product product)
    {
        System.out.print("The productName is" +product.getProdName());
        productRepository.save(product);
        return product.getId();
    }

    @CrossOrigin(origins = "http://localhost:8080")
    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET, value="/products/{id}")
    public product show(@PathVariable String id){
        return productRepository.findOne(id);
    }

    @CrossOrigin(origins = "http://localhost:8080")
    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.PUT, value="/products/{id}")
    public product update(@PathVariable String id, @RequestBody product product){
        product prod = productRepository.findOne(id);
        if(product.getProdName()!= null)
            prod.setProdName(product.getProdName());
        if(product.getProdDesc()!= null)
            prod.setProdDesc(product.getProdDesc());
        if(product.getProdPrice()!=null)
            prod.setProdPrice(product.getProdPrice());
        if(product.getProdImage()!=null)
            prod.setProdImage(product.getProdImage());
        if(product.getProdManufacturer()!=null)
            prod.setProdManufacturer(product.getProdManufacturer());
        return prod;
    }

    @CrossOrigin(origins = "http://localhost:8080")
    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.DELETE, value="/products/{id}")
    public String delete(@PathVariable String id)
    {
        product product = productRepository.findOne(id);
        productRepository.delete(product);

        return "product deleted";
    }
}
```

I have my model file as:

product.java

```
package com.spring.restapi.models;

import org.springframework.data.annotation.Id;
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.mapping.Document;

@Document(collection = "products")

public class product {

@Id

String id;
String prodName;
String prodDesc;
Double prodPrice;
String prodImage;
String prodManufacturer;

public product() {
}

public product (String prodName, String prodDesc, Double prodPrice, String prodImage, String prodManufacturer)
{
    this.prodName  = prodName;
    this.prodDesc  = prodDesc;
    this.prodPrice = prodPrice;
    this.prodImage = prodImage;
    this.prodManufacturer = prodManufacturer;
}

public String getId()
{
    return id;
}

public void setId(String id){
    this.id =id;    
}

public String getProdName(){
        return prodName;
}
public void setProdName(String prodName){
    this.prodName = prodName;
}
public String getProdDesc(){
    return prodDesc;
}
public void setProdDesc(String prodDesc){
    this.prodDesc = prodDesc;
}

public Double getProdPrice(){
    return prodPrice;
}

public void setProdPrice(Double prodPrice)
{
    this.prodPrice = prodPrice;
}

public String getProdImage(){
        return prodImage;
}
public void setProdImage(String prodImage){
    this.prodImage = prodImage;
}

public String getProdManufacturer(){
    return prodManufacturer;
}

public void setProdManufacturer(String prodManufacturer){
    this.prodManufacturer = prodManufacturer;
}

}
```

and the last one product repository .java as

```
package com.spring.restapi.repositories;

import com.spring.restapi.models.product;
import org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository;


public interface ProductRepository extends CrudRepository<product, String> {

    @Override
    product findOne(String id);

    @Override
    void delete(product deleted);
}
```

Now I am trying to a post request with all the fields from the front end code like this:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import jquery from 'jquery';
import $ from 'jquery';
import logo from './logo.svg';
import './App.css';
// import '../node_modules/jquery/jquery.min.js';

class App extends Component {

      addProduct() 
  {
    var productObject = {
      "name": document.getElementById('productName').value,
      "price":  document.getElementById('productPrice').value,
      "description":document.getElementById('productDescription').value,
      "manufacturer":document.getElementById('productManufacturer').value
    };
    var dataPushed ={
      productName: productObject.name,
      productPrice:productObject.price,
      productDescription:productObject.description,
      productManufacturer:productObject.manufacturer
    };
    console.log("The Data is ",JSON.stringify(dataPushed));
    var dataPushedForFinal = JSON.stringify(dataPushed);
    //var dataForPost = JSON.stringify(productObject);
  $.ajax({
        type:"POST",
        url:'http://localhost:8080/products',
        data:dataPushedForFinal,
        contentType:"application/json",
        dataType:"json",
        crossOrigin:true,
        crossDomain:true,
      });


    //console.log("The value collected is",ProductName + "and " , ProductPrice+"and", ProductManufacturer);
  }
  render() {

    return (
     <div className="mainPageDiv"> 
      <div className="App">
        <header className="App-header">
          <h1 className="App-title">Welcome to Stock Maintenance</h1>
        </header> 
      </div>
      <div className = "container-fluid">
        <div className="row">
          <div className ="col-md-6">
             <div className="myFormDiv">
                    <div className="form_main">
                <h4 className="heading"><strong>Product </strong> Details <span></span></h4>
                <div className="form">

                      <input type="text" id="productName" required="" placeholder="Please Enter Product Name"  name="name" className="txt"/>
                      <input type="text" id="productPrice"required="" placeholder="Please Enter Product Price" name="mob" className="txt"/>
                      <input type="text" id="productManufacturer"required="" placeholder="Please Enter Product Manufacturer" name="email" className="txt"/>

                    <textarea placeholder="Please Enter product description" id="productDescription" name="mess" type="text" className="txt_3"></textarea>
                   <center>   <input type="submit" value="submit" name="submit" className="txt2" onClick ={this.addProduct}/> </center>

            </div>
            </div>
            </div>
        </div>

          <div className = "col-md-6">
            <div className = "myFormDiv">

              <h4 className="heading"><strong>Product </strong> table <span></span></h4>
            <div class="table-responsive col-md-12">
        <table id="sort2" class="grid table table-bordered table-sortable">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                  <th>ID</th>
                  <th>Product Name</th>
                  <th>Product Price</th>
                  <th>Product Manufacturer</th>
                  <th>Product Description</th></tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td>1</td>
                    <td><input type="text" value="name 1" class="form-control"/></td>
                    <td><input type="text" value="email 1" class="form-control"/></td>
                    <td><input type="text" value="email 1" class="form-control"/></td>
                    <td><input type="text" value="email 1" class="form-control"/></td>
                    <td><button class="btn btn-primary ">update</button>&nbsp;<button class="btn btn-danger">delete</button></td> 
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>2</td>
                    <td><input type="text" value="name 2" class="form-control"/></td>
                    <td><input type="text" value="email 2" class="form-control"/></td>
                    <td><input type="text" value="email 1" class="form-control"/></td>
                    <td><input type="text" value="email 1" class="form-control"/></td>
                    <td><button class="btn btn-primary ">update</button><button class="btn btn-danger">delete</button></td> 
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>3</td>
                    <td><input type="text" value="name 3" class="form-control"/></td>
                    <td><input type="text" value="email 3" class="form-control"/></td>
                    <td><input type="text" value="email 1" class="form-control"/></td>
                    <td><input type="text" value="email 1" class="form-control"/></td>

                    <td><button class="btn btn-primary ">update</button>&nbsp;<button class="btn btn-danger">delete</button></td> 
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
        </div>
            </div>
          </div>

        </div>
       </div> 
     </div>  
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

But data is not getting added into mongodb only it is generatinf ID but when i am trying to add it with postman it is getting added.

please can someone help i am totaly new in springboot and mongodb.

Answer (score 0):

your REST service is expecting a JSON object that should mimic the `product` class

1. make sure you the data you are posting in JS is the same as your `product` including types (so you'll need to ensure price is a `Number`, not a string)
2. <strike>don't use `JSON.stringify` before ajax POST</strike>

something like

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    ...
    data: JSON.stringify({
        id: null, 
        prodName: document.getElementById('productName').value, 
        prodDesc: document.getElementById('productDescription').value,
        prodPrice: Number(document.getElementById('productPrice').value),
        prodImage: '...',
        prodManufacturer: document.getElementById('productManufacturer').value
    }),
    ...
});
```

Comment: Hi Mike i am getting this error {"timestamp":1517761525579,"status":400,"error":"Bad Request","exception":"org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException","message":"JSON parse error: Unrecognized token 'id': was expecting ('true', 'false' or 'null'); nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParseException: Unrecognized token 'id': was expecting ('true', 'false' or 'null')\n at [Source: java.io.PushbackInputStream@427b93c6; line: 1, column: 4]","path":"/products"}

Comment: No even i removed ID it is not working and it is occuring with the error

org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException"

Comment: It looks like `JSON.stringify` is needed ... see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3983556/using-jquery-to-post-json-object-to-spring-3-controller#3987156