# POST Ajax Call not send JSON Content and GET Unsupported Media Type

Tags: json, ajax, spring-mvc

I have a Java API with **Spring MVC**. I tested a endpoint with Postman and it was working fine (raw body of type JSON). Now, I was testing the same endpoint from a web page with an jQuery ajax call and looks like the format that are being sended is text.

This is my ajax Request

```
var jsonData = {
    "username" : $("#username").val(),
    "password" : $("#password").val()
};
console.log(jsonData);
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: "/app/sing-in",
    data: jsonData,
    contentType: "application/json",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR){
        console.log("textStatus:" + textStatus);
        console.log("jqXHR:" + jqXHR.status);
    },
    error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
        console.log("ERROR-textStatus:" + textStatus);
        console.log("ERROR-jqXHR:" + jqXHR.status);
    },
});
```

This is the error that I am receiving:

```
timestamp: "2020-04-07T18:10:30.242+0000"
status: 400
error: "Bad Request"
message: "JSON parse error: Unrecognized token 'username': was expecting (JSON String, Number, Array, Object or token 'null', 'true' or 'false'); nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParseException: Unrecognized token 'username': was expecting (JSON String, Number, Array, Object or token 'null', 'true' or 'false')↵ at [Source: (PushbackInputStream); line: 1, column: 10]"
path: "/app/sing-in":
```

It's weird looks like I am not sending a JSON object in my request but a simple text.

[image]

Could this use a javascript object instead a JSON object? Can I make a generic conversion here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use `JSON.stringify()`  on data before sending Ajax.

```
JSON.stringify(jsonData);
```

Refer this for more : https://stackoverflow.com/a/3987156/6572971

Comment: I thouth that jQuery will make this automatically. Thank!

Comment: jQuery doesn't encode Javascript objects into JSON automatically. Glad it helped.